# Why supportedInterfaceOrientations is calling multiple times in ios6

Tags: iphone, uiinterfaceorientation

In my ios6 application supportedInterface orientation method calling 2 times. How to prevent this and how to make it to call only once in ios6. please let me know the way to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}




- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    orientationControlString=@"thumbnailNotSelected";
    NSLog(@"appdelegate.previewImageScallingmethodCallControlValue value is %d",appdelegate.previewImageScallingmethodCallControlValue); //Gestures settings
    viewsHiddingGesture=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(operationsOnViews:)];
    viewsHiddingGesture.cancelsTouchesInView=NO;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:viewsHiddingGesture];


    launchPopOverGesture=[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(annotationsPopOver:)];
    launchPopOverGesture.minimumPressDuration=0.8;
    launchPopOverGesture.allowableMovement=NO;
    launchPopOverGesture.cancelsTouchesInView=NO;
    [tiledView addGestureRecognizer:launchPopOverGesture];
    addAnnotationsGesture=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(addPinAnnotation:)];
    annotationScroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(258, 700);

    appdelegate =(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    UIInterfaceOrientation statusBarOrientation =[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;


    NSLog(@"statusBarOrientation in supported interface orientations is %d",statusBarOrientation);

    NSLog(@"PREVIEWIMAGESCALLING VALUE IS %d",appdelegate.previewImageScallingmethodCallControlValue);



    if(statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft  || statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        // code for landscape orientation
        patternRemovalValue=0;

        [self landscapeOrientation];


        if(appdelegate.previewImageScallingmethodCallControlValue==1)
        {
            [self previewImageScallingInLandscape];
            firstOrientationChange=YES;
            appdelegate.getImagesResponseArrayObjectNumber=0;

        }

        else if(((appdelegate.previewImageScallingmethodCallControlValue%2)==0) && (appdelegate.previewImageScallingmethodCallControlValue > 1))
        {
            [self previewImageScallingInLandscape];
            firstOrientationChange=NO;


        }

        appdelegate.orientationChangesCount++;
        patternRemovalValue++;
        appdelegate.previewImageScallingmethodCallControlValue++;


    }
    else if(statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown || statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)

    {
        // code for Portrait orientation
        patternRemovalValue=0;

        [self potraitOrientation];


        if(appdelegate.previewImageScallingmethodCallControlValue==1)
        {
            [self previewImageScallingInPotrait];
            firstOrientationChange=YES;
            appdelegate.getImagesResponseArrayObjectNumber=0;


        }

        else if(((appdelegate.previewImageScallingmethodCallControlValue%2)==0) && (appdelegate.previewImageScallingmethodCallControlValue > 1))
        {
            [self previewImageScallingInPotrait];
            firstOrientationChange=NO;

        }


        patternRemovalValue++;
        appdelegate.previewImageScallingmethodCallControlValue++;


    }

return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Comment: yes sure but it is lengthy how can i post please let me know.I am new to stackoverflow so i dont know the procedure.

Comment: Hi arun thanks for your reply. But here limit is there.Ok i will ask one more question with code please give a reply to that. It's so urgent arun please help me.

Comment: hold a min just edit your answer and add your code and post

Comment: Hi there is a limit in characters here so...

Comment: Hi i go it but while submit the edited question it is showing an error occured while editing like that...

Comment: Hi Spynet i edited my question, can you please go through the code and try to show me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this happens, but in my experience you must assume that supportedInterfaceOrientations will be called multiple times, and have your logic deal with that. You should move most of your code out of there and into somewhere else, perhaps loadView or your init function. The standard practice is to only have code in supportedInterfaceOrientations that immediately reports which orientations you support.